# JS timer and mysql not in sync

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<script>
<!--
var milisec=0
var seconds=0
document.d.d2.value='0'
function display(){
if (milisec>=9){
milisec=0
seconds+=1
}
else
milisec+=1
document.d.d2.value=seconds+'.'+milisec
setTimeout("display()",100)
}
display();


    setInterval(function(){
         $.post("procesare.php",{score: seconds},function(data){

            $('#text').html(data);

           });
        },1000);

//-->
</script>
```

This is my JS code. I'm trying to store in database the time a user is on my index. Here is my "procesare.php" where I call the queries:

```
if(isset($_POST['score'])){
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT nickname, score FROM users ORDER BY score DESC");
    $rank = 1;

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<br />{$rank}. 
                  {$row['nickname']} -->
                  {$row['score']}";

            $rank++;
        }
    }
$qry="SELECT score FROM users WHERE username='{$_SESSION['user']}'";
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_fetch_row($result);

$total = $_POST['score'] + $result[0];
$qry="UPDATE users SET score='$total' WHERE username='{$_SESSION['user']}'";
mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
```

My problem is that the JS timer works normally, second by second, but in the database, it is a chaos. The time increases randomly..... I cant figure out why ....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're ultimately trying to do, but it seems a bit fishy.

I'm also not clear on what 'chaos in database' means. For what it's worth, you probably should update like so:

```
$qry="UPDATE users SET score = score + '$_POST['score']' WHERE username='{$_SESSION['user']}'";
```

You don't need the separate query for looking up existing score. Just increment it. You should also watch out for sql injection.

Comment: Im trying to make a website, in which every user get rewarded with 1 score/ seocnd on page. Hoping that people will get competitive and enetr on my site. Thanks for the answer, ill try and let u know if it worked

Comment: I finally managed to fix it. I had a logical error. Every second i was adding my current time, not  a second per second . if u get me. Thanks a lot anyways:D

Comment: So if I open my browser console and type: $.post("procesare.php",{score: 1000000}); I'll quickly be at the top of the leaderboard? :)